# Get total number of user where username have defferrent case

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, count

I have SQL table where username have different cases for example "ACCOUNTS\Ninja.Developer" or "ACCOUNTS\ninja.developer"
I want to find the how many records where username where first in first and last name capitalize ? how can use Regex to find the total ?

```
x table 
User 

    "ACCOUNTS\James.McAvoy"
    "ACCOUNTS\michael.fassbender"
    "ACCOUNTS\nicholas.hoult"
    "ACCOUNTS\Oscar.Isaac"
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What does "number of records that capitalize and all lower case" mean? What exactly do you want to total?

Comment: I want to find the how many records where username where first in first and last name capitalize ?

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: I added tag and it SQL server

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper . . . Do you have an extension that supports regular expressions?  They are not built into SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
select count(*)
from t
where name rlike 'ACCOUNTS\[A-Z][a-z0-9]*[.][A-Z][a-z0-9]*'
```

Of course, different databases implement regular expressions differently, so the actual comparator may not be `rlike`.

In SQL Server, you can do:

```
select count(*)
from t
where name like 'ACCOUNTS\[A-Z][^.][.][A-Z]%';
```

You might need to be sure that you have a case-sensitive collation.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases in MS SQL string collation is case insensitive so we need some trick. Here is an example:

```
declare @accts table(acct varchar(100))
--sample data
insert @accts values
('ACCOUNTS\James.McAvoy'),
('ACCOUNTS\michael.fassbender'),
('ACCOUNTS\nicholas.hoult'),
('ACCOUNTS\Oscar.Isaac') 

;with accts as (
select 
--cleanup and split values
left(replace(acct,'ACCOUNTS\',''),charindex('.',replace(acct,'ACCOUNTS\',''),0)-1) frst,
right(replace(acct,'ACCOUNTS\',''),charindex('.',replace(acct,'ACCOUNTS\',''),0)) last
from @accts
)
,groups as (--add comparison columns
select frst, last, 
case when CAST(frst as varbinary(max)) = CAST(lower(frst) as varbinary(max)) then 'lower' else 'Upper' end frstCase, --circumvert case insensitive
case when CAST(last as varbinary(max)) = CAST(lower(last) as varbinary(max)) then 'lower' else 'Upper' end lastCase
from accts
)
--and gather fruit
select frstCase, lastCase, count(frst) cnt
from groups
group by frstCase,lastCase
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague but;

You might be looking for the `DISTINCT` command.

[REF](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

I don't think you need regex.

Maybe do something like:

- Get distinct names from Table X as Table A
- Use inputs table A as where clause on Table X
- count
- union

I hope this helps,
Rhys

Answer (score 0):

Given your example set you can use a combination of techniques. First if the user name always begins with "ACCOUNTS\" then you can use substr to select the characters that start after the "\" character.

For the first name:
Then you can use a regex function to see if it matches against [A-Z] or [a-z] assuming your username must start with an alpha character.

For the last name:
Use the instr function on the substr and search for the character '.' and again apply the regex function to match against [A-Z] or [a-z] to see if the last name starts with an upper or a lower character.

To total:
Select all matches where both first and last match against upper and do a count. Repeat for the lower matches and you'll have both totals.